# How do I split a TypeScript class into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found a lot of examples and also tried myself to split a module into several files. So I get that one, very handy. But it's also practical sometimes to split a class for the same reason. Say I have a couple of methods and I don't want to cram everything into one long file.

I'm looking for something similar to the **partial** declaration in C#.

Comment: IMO, it doesn't make sense to split something that should represent a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) into multiple files. The `partial` C# declaration really shines when one partial is auto-generated code, but this won't be the case with your TypeScript, right? Is your class taking on too many roles? Could you turn it >1 classes?

Comment: You have a point. Maybe I could just break all methods into a module that could act as a helper instead of having helper methods on the class. I'll consider that.

Comment: @spender I tried your suggestion. And I must say it only "worked" partially. Some methods does clearly belong outside the class, but some metods are really logical to have inside the class. Primarily data handling methods that sorts, filters and somehow deals with the data inside the class. So I once again ended up with having quite a large class file that sure would have been more convenient to split up in several files. I cannot see how it would be more logical to put those methods in other classes. It just fragments the code as I see it. But I don't say I'm neccessarily right... =)

Comment: I disagree with the first comment. I have found many times that partial classes separated across many files are very useful. this is true primarily when you have a team of developers working together on the same class.

Comment: @spender: It's also helpful when you want a class that is partially written by hand and partially by a code generator.

Comment: I solved this with regular JS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142995/1599699

Comment: I'm here because my class (pretty simple CRUD) is almost 1k lines because of overloads and type definitions. Ouch.

Comment: @Nathan what class is big enough for multiple devs to work on it at the same time? when you hit above 500 lines of code for a single class, it is time to think about refactoring it. That is not always possible, but much more often than devs want to admit that it is. just create new layers by outsourcing code that belongs together in subclasses. makes working with multiple devs and git much easier as well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't.

There was a feature request to implement partial classes, first on [CodePlex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1612) and later on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563), but [on 2017-04-04](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563#issuecomment-291300044) it was declared out-of-scope. A number of reasons are given, the main takeaway seems to be that they want to avoid deviating from ES6 as much as possible:

> TypeScript *already* has too many TS-specific class features [...] Adding yet another TS-specific class feature is another straw on the camel's back that we should avoid if we can. [...] So if there's some scenario that really knocks it out of the park for adding partial classes, then that scenario ought to be able to justify itself through the TC39 process.

Comment: If the goal of typescript is to remain close to ES6, why does it exist? We already have ES6

Comment: @Jose TypeScript was publicly released in October 2012, nearly 3 years before the ES6 spec was finalised. It was a very different landscape then, writing JavaScript in an organised way was quite challenging. TypeScript wasn't the only alternative language, we had CoffeeScript and Dart for example. Since then, JavaScript has evolved a lot, in part thanks to those projects. Today, the most significant feature that TypeScript provides is static typing.

Comment: @Stijn Totally agree. But we have Flow for that now. ES# + Flow beats Typescript at every turn by far, and transpiles rather than compile! I believe it is lovely that Typescript is out there to provide inspiration and competition, so that Babel and Flow keep getting better. But I'll never choose that mammoth of a thing over a much better performance, more elegant and as feature-rich ES# + Flow. Would you??

Comment: @EdoardoL'Astorina I haven't done a lot of frontend development during the past couple years, in fact it's the first time I hear about Flow so I can't comment on it. But I'm not surprised that alternatives have appeared.

Comment: @Jose ES6 (and TS for that matter) is an attempt to turn JS into an OOP. It is not an OOP, it is LISP with C-like syntax. The data types are LISP data types, the implicit type conversions are LISP behaviour and the closures are LISP closures. If you understand LISP, the behaviour of `this` isn't even slightly surprising, what's _weird_ is all the pretense of OOP. The people who created TS and ES6 probably _did_ understand this, and they were trying to re-make the language to match the misperceptions of its users and validate the invalid.

Comment: "they want to avoid deviating from ES6 as much as possible". Heaven forbid we have an enterprise-class programming language for the web.

Answer (score 92):

Lately I use this pattern:

```
// file class.ts
import { getValue, setValue } from "./methods";

class BigClass {
    public getValue = getValue;
    public setValue = setValue;

    protected value = "a-value";
}
```

```
// file methods.ts
import { BigClass } from "./class";

function getValue(this: BigClass) {
    return this.value;
}

function setValue(this: BigClass, value: string ) {
   this.value = value;
}
```

This way we can put methods in a seperate file. Now there is some circular dependency thing going on here. The file `class.ts` imports from `methods.ts` and `methods.ts` imports from `class.ts`. This may seem scary, but this is not a problem. As long as the code execution is not circular everything is fine and in this case the `methods.ts` file is not executing any code from the `class.ts` file. NP!

You could also use it with a generic class like this:

```
class BigClass<T> {
    public getValue = getValue;
    public setValue = setValue;

    protected value?: T;
}

function getValue<T>(this: BigClass<T>) {
    return this.value;
}

function setValue<T>(this: BigClass<T>, value: T) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a fantastic solution I'm going to give it a try with my team on our next project!

Comment: @Elmer This works great! For anyone curious, it's documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) (`this` parameters)

Comment: Nice solution, the only problem I've found is that you can't call the class private methods within the external funcion.

Comment: @Galactus that's right! but you can access protected members! It's not the same but it could be a (maybe dirty) solution.

Comment: How would I use this if `BigClass` has type arguments? e.g.

`BigClass<T>`

Comment: I am a bit confused, you need to import the BigClass (file) in the methods' file. So, the methods' file depends on the BigClass's file. Also, you need to import the method's file in the BigClass to be able to use them. So, the BigClass depends on the methods' file.
How you would load these files when there is a loop. Unless you use an abstraction. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HamidMayeli You are right! So you would have a method file that imports from a class file, the class file imports from the method file. This is circular! However, this will not cause any problems in as long as there is no circular execution of code. This is not the case here.

Comment: @bmarti44 That is a good question! I actually never tried it with a generic class, after some fiddeling I updated the answer!

Comment: @Elmer that works great! It seems I would need to refactor the functions (if they already existed without a type) to accept a type argument (but it looks like it's not a huge deal for my use case).

Comment: @Elmer, this approach seems great, but in fact it has a big drawback: it actually creates additional fields in the class instead of using prototypes for that. This might greatly increase memory usage and will make the code much slower if you have many instances of that class, also creation and deletion of such instances might be slower. So this approach seems to be applicable if perfomance isn't an issue.

Comment: @YuriYaryshev I would love to see some numbers on that, or is all of this based on assumption? Also, I would not choose js if performance is critical.

Comment: Love this solution! A minor limitation is that functions lose their doc strings that are defined in `methods.ts`.

Comment: Regarding the circular imports, it may be clearer to use `import type { BigClass } ...` to import the type alone, which makes it more clear that there isn't a circular dep on the implementations.

Answer (score 28):

I use this (works in typescript 2.2.2):

```
class BigClass implements BigClassPartOne, BigClassPartTwo {
    // only public members are accessible in the
    // class parts!
    constructor(public secret: string) { }

    // this is ugly-ish, but it works!
    methodOne = BigClassPartOne.prototype.methodOne;
    methodTwo = BigClassPartTwo.prototype.methodTwo;
}

class BigClassPartOne {
    methodOne(this: BigClass) {
        return this.methodTwo();
    }
}

class BigClassPartTwo {
    methodTwo(this: BigClass) {
        return this.secret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this "prototyping" workaround kills the intellisense?

Comment: No! It's intellisense friendly (at least in vscode)

Comment: You should make the methods of the parts static (`static methodOne(this: BigClass) {...}`) to get rid of `.prototype`.

Comment: this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876782/how-do-i-split-a-typescript-class-into-multiple-files/52393598#52393598 is a better solution!

Comment: @Elmer, this approach seems great, but in fact it has a big drawback (same for the one above): it actually creates additional fields in the class instead of using prototypes for that. This might greatly increase memory usage and will make the code much slower if you have many instances of that class, also creation and deletion of such instances might be slower. So this approach seems to be applicable if perfomance isn't an issue.

Comment: @YuriYaryshev you're right, even though it is very unlikely that this will ever be a real problem, it will result in some overhead! I posted a different solution that is more efficient!

Comment: @user11104582 I also realized that by using static methods, you can't cross-reference the methods within the same class, e.g. you can't call methodOne within methodTwo if both were declared within BigClassOne otherwise you get a "Property ABC does not exist on type XYZ" error.

Answer (score 11):

I use plain subclassing when converting large old multi file javascript classes which use 'prototype' into multiple typescript files:

bigclassbase.ts:

```
class BigClassBase {
    methodOne() {
        return 1;
    }

}
export { BigClassBase }
```

bigclass.ts:

```
import { BigClassBase } from './bigclassbase'

class BigClass extends BigClassBase {
    methodTwo() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

You can import BigClass in any other typescript file.

Comment: but I can not extends more than 1 Class. How can I "extend" 100 Classes?

Comment: In this case you can use a [Mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) I never use them btw… I prefer a composition pattern.

Answer (score 4):

A modified version of proposed pattern.

```
// temp.ts contents
import {getValue, setValue} from "./temp2";

export class BigClass {
    // @ts-ignore - to ignore TS2564: Property 'getValue' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
    public getValue:typeof getValue;

    // @ts-ignore - to ignore TS2564: Property 'setValue' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
    public setValue:typeof setValue;
    protected value = "a-value";
}

BigClass.prototype.getValue = getValue;
BigClass.prototype.setValue = setValue;

//======================================================================
// temp2.ts contents
import { BigClass } from "./temp";

export function getValue(this: BigClass) {
    return this.value;
}

export function setValue(this: BigClass, value: string ) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

**Pros**

- Doesn't create additional fields in class instances so there is no overhead: in construction, destruction, no additional memory used. Field declations in typescript are only used for typings here, they don't create fields in Javascript runtime.
- Intellisence is OK (tested in Webstorm)

**Cons**

- ts-ignore is needed
- Uglier syntax than @Elmer's answer

The rest properties of solutions are same.

Comment: I wonder why this is not more upvoted. As far as I understand it it is the best solution because it actually answers the OPs question how to accieve "something similar to the partial declaration in C#". All other solutions add functions to the instances instead of the prototype of the class. This is the solution I use.

Comment: Add `declare` and no ugli code any more. `declare public setValue: typeof setValue;`. But additional con to you solution it is not possible to prototype private and protected methods.

Answer (score 4):

Modules let you extend a typescript class from another file:

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
  name: string;
}

import './user-talk';
```

**user-talk.ts**

```
import { User } from './user';

class UserTalk {
  talk (this:User) {
    console.log(`${this.name} says relax`);
  }
}

User.prototype.sayHi = UserTalk.prototype.sayHi;

declare module './user' {
  interface User extends UserTalk { }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import { User } from './user';

const u = new User();
u.name = 'Frankie';
u.talk();
> Frankie says relax
```

**If you have a lot of methods, you might try this:**

```
// user.ts
export class User {
  static extend (cls:any) {
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cls.prototype)) {
      if (key !== 'constructor') {
        this.prototype[key] = cls.prototype[key];
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}

// user-talk.ts
...
User.extend(UserTalk);
```

**Or add the subclass to the prototype chain:**

```
...
static extend (cls:any) {
  let prototype:any = this;
  while (true) {
    const next = prototype.prototype.__proto__;
    if (next === Object.prototype) break;
    prototype = next;
  }
  prototype.prototype.__proto__ = cls.prototype;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work really well with no performance hit and the ability to use `protected` class members. Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/cjbarth/pen/XWEggwV

Answer (score 2):

You can use [multi file namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces).

Validation.ts:

```
namespace Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

LettersOnlyValidator.ts (uses the StringValidator from above):

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" /> 
namespace Validation {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Test.ts (uses both StringValidator and LettersOnlyValidator from above):

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
/// <reference path="LettersOnlyValidator.ts" />

// Some samples to try
let strings = ["Hello", "101"];

// Validators to use
let validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
validators["Letters only"] = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `Function.call` that js already comes with.

`class-a.ts`

```js
Class ClassA {
  bitten: false;

  constructor() {
    console.log("Bitten: ", this.bitten);
  }

  biteMe = () => biteMe.call(this);
}
```

and in other file `bite-me.ts`

```js
export function biteMe(this: ClassA) {
  // do some stuff
  // here this refers to ClassA.prototype

  this.bitten = true;

  console.log("Bitten: ", this.bitten);
}
```

// using it

```js
const state = new ClassA();
// Bitten: false

state.biteMe();
// Bitten: true
```

For more information have a look at the definition of [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: This approach seems great, but in fact it has a big drawback: it actually creates additional fields in the class instead of using prototypes for that. This might greatly increase memory usage and will make the code much slower if you have many instances of that class, also creation and deletion of such instances might be slower. So this approach seems to be applicable if perfomance isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [@partial](https://github.com/mustafah/partials) decorator acts as a simplified syntax that may help divide functionality of a single class into multiple  class files ... https://github.com/mustafah/partials

Answer (score 1):

```
// Declaration file
class BigClass {
  declare method: (n: number, s: string) => string;
}

// Implementation file
BigClass.prototype.method = function (this: BigClass, n: number, s: string) {
  return '';
}
```

The downside of this approach is that it is possible to declare a method but to forget to actually add its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We can extend class methods gradually with `prototype` and `Interface` definition:

```js
import login from './login';
import staffMe from './staff-me';

interface StaffAPI {
  login(this: StaffAPI, args: LoginArgs): Promise<boolean>;
  staffsMe(this: StaffAPI): Promise<StaffsMeResponse>;
}

class StaffAPI {
  // class body
}

StaffAPI.prototype.login = login;
StaffAPI.prototype.staffsMe = staffsMe;

export default StaffAPI;
```

Comment: This works great if you aren't dealing with `private` or `protected` members.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have been doing it
[Mixins approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern)

Answer (score -1):

To add to @Elmer's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393598/707162), I added following to get it to work in separate file.

**some-function-service-helper.ts**

```
import { SomeFunctionService } from "./some-function-service";

export function calculateValue1(this: SomeFunctionService) {
...
}
```

**some-function-service.ts**

```
import * as helper from './some-function-service-helper';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeFunctionService {

    calculateValue1 = helper.calculateValue1;  //  helper function delcaration used for getNewItem

    public getNewItem() {
        var one = this.calculateValue1();
    }
```

Comment: This approach seems great, but in fact it has a big drawback (same as the for ones above): it actually creates additional fields in the class instead of using prototypes for that. This might greatly increase memory usage and will make the code much slower if you have many instances of that class, also creation and deletion of such instances might be slower. So this approach seems to be applicable if perfomance isn't an issue.