# Typescript : Add a method on a class from another module / Populate a namespace from different modules

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, commonjs, partial-classes

### The story

I am building a modular library for math operations. I also want to divide the library into multiple modules : `core`, `relational`, `vectors`, and so on. The modules can be used on their own (but all depend on the `core` module)

1. I know it's not possible to use partial classes [How do I split a TypeScript class into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876782/how-do-i-split-a-typescript-class-into-multiple-files) / https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563

### The problem :

The `core` module defines the `Set` class, which is a mathematical set. It defines operations such as `Set#add`, `Set#remove`.

Though, the **optional** `relational` module adds a `Set#product`operator on the `Set`class.

Other modules could also add other operations on the `Set` class. I want to keep the possibility of adding functionality when I will see fit.

### The question

1. With **typescript**, how can I add a method on a class that resides in another module ?
2. How can I arrange the typings so that the user of my library will see the `Set#product` in his code completion  **only if he installed the `relational` module** ? Otherwise he only sees the `#add` and `#remove` operations ?

I am developing this library for `node.js`, but also use `browserify` to bundle it for browser use.

```js
// core/set.ts 

export class Set {
  add(element){}
  remove(element){}
}


// relational/set.ts

import {Set} from './../core/set.ts';

Set.prototype.product = function(){} // ?


// app/index.js

import {core} from 'mylib';

var set = new Set();
set.add();
set.remove();
// set.product() is not available


// app/index2.js

import {core} from 'mylib';
import {relational} from 'mylib';

var set = new Set();
set.add();
set.remove();
set.product() //is available
```

### Bonus question

All these modules are made to be available through a common namespace, let's call it `MyLibrary`. The `core` module adds `MyLibrary.Core`, and the `relational` module adds some objects into the `MyLibrary.Core`, and also adds `MyLibrary.Relational`.

Let's say I publish another module, only used to act as a facade for the other modules. Let's call this module `my-library`.

If a user installs the `my-library`, `core` and `relational` modules with npm.

```
npm install my-library && npm install core and nom-install relational
```

In the client application I would like the user of the library to only have to write

```
var lib = require('my-library');
```

Then, my-library would automatically check all installed MyLibrary modules, require them and populate the MyLibrary namespace and return it.

How an I tell the `my-library` module, the first time it is accessed, in both node and browser env to

1. Check for any available MyLibrary module (browser and node environments)
2. Run a method for each module (to install them in the namespace)
3. Return that nice fruity namespace

Comment: Why don't you use traditional class inheritance?

Comment: Because multiple modules can add functionality to the same class.

Comment: It's like c# partial classes

Answer (score 2):

If you're just writing declaration files, you can use interfaces instead and do something like what [`moment-timezone`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts) does.

### moment.d.ts

```
declare module moment {
    interface Moment {
        // ...
    }

    interface MomentStatic {
        // ...
    }
}
declare module 'moment' {
    var _tmp: moment.MomentStatic;
    export = _tmp;
}
```

### moment-timezone.d.ts

Just redeclare the same interfaces with extra functions.

```
declare module moment {
    interface Moment {
        tz(): void;
    }

    interface MomentStatic {
        tz(): void;
    }
}
declare module 'moment-timezone' {
    var _tmp: moment.MomentStatic;
    export = _tmp;
}
```

Both packages are identical now, and `moment` gets the new methods automatically.

Comment: Hi there. The problem is I'm writing the whole thing in typescript , not just declaration files...

Comment: In that case I believe you'll have to write declaration files manually or use a tool to generate them. In both cases you can only rely on interfaces. No other option that I know of unfortunately.