# Partial classes in typescript

Tags: typescript, partial-classes

files.ts

```
export class ServiceUrls {
 static baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:52949/V1/';
    static baseImageUrl: string = 'http://localhost:52949/';
}
```

filess1.ts

```
extends interface  ServiceUrls{
 static baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:52949/V1/';
    static baseImageUrl: string = 'http://localhost:52949/';
}
```

How to implement partial class in typescript.How should i give reference of same class to make it work like partial class.If i give same class name in files1.ts its giving error declaration or statement expected.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a TypeScript class into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876782/how-do-i-split-a-typescript-class-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2):

I created and I'm using [@partial](https://github.com/mustafah/partials) decorator acts as a simplified syntax that may help divide functionality of a single class into multiple class files ... https://github.com/mustafah/partials

Answer (score 0):

According to [github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563), they have their concerns of not implementing the **partial** keyword. Therefore, you will need to write it yourself.

This task is no more than mixing prototypes. However, if you want a reliable one, you need to be very careful with method and property conflicts, also with `type inference` support.

I've written one and published on [npm package partial_classes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/partial_classes). You can use it by `npm i partial_classes`. And here is a simple method shows how to do this.

```
function combineClasses<T>(...constructors: T[]) {
    class CombinedClass {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            constructors.forEach(constructor => {
                const instance = new constructor(...args); // copy instance property
                Object.assign(this, instance);
            });
        }
    }

    constructors.forEach(constructor => { // copy prototype property
        let proto = constructor.prototype;
        while (proto !== Object.prototype) { // iterate until proto chain ends
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto).forEach(name => {
                const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, name);
                if (!descriptor) return;
                Object.defineProperty(CombinedClass.prototype, name, descriptor);
            });
            proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
        }
    });
    return CombinedClass
}
```

then use as

```js
import combineClasses from 'partial_classes'
class ServiceUrlsFoo { }
class ServiceUrlsBar { }
const ServiceUrls = combineClasses(ServiceUrlsFoo, ServiceUrlsBar)
const instance = new ServiceUrls()
```